# Why can't I replace BeginPaint() with ValidateRect()?

Tags: c, winapi, gdi

From my understanding, `BeginPaint` and `EndPaint` helps paint the screen and validates the rectangle that it paints, this also prevents `WM_PAINT` messages from being spammed since there will be no more invalid regions in the window.

With my understanding, I thought that theoretically speaking, if I were to use `BitBlt()` to paint the window in `WM_CREATE`, then use `ValidateRect` to Validate the entire client region, the code would work. However, I tried it and it doesn't, suggesting that there could be something possibly wrong with my understanding, or code. Could someone please explain to me where I went wrong?

Here is the code that I used, `IDB_BITMAP1` can be replaced with any appropriate Bitmap. Do note the comment in `WM_PAINT` to reproduce the issue. Thanks for reading!

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "resource.h"

HBITMAP hBitMap = NULL;

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        BITMAP infoBM;
        hBitMap = LoadBitmap(GetModuleHandle(NULL), IDB_BITMAP1);
        if (hBitMap == NULL)
        {
            MessageBoxA(NULL, "COULD NOT LOAD CAT BITMAP", "ERROR", MB_OK);
        }
        HDC winDC = GetDC(hwnd);
        HDC hMem = CreateCompatibleDC(winDC);
        GetObject(hBitMap, sizeof(infoBM), &infoBM);
        HBITMAP hMemOld = SelectObject(hMem, hBitMap);
        BitBlt(winDC, 0, 0, infoBM.bmWidth, infoBM.bmHeight, hMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
        SelectObject(hMem, hMemOld);
        DeleteDC(hMem);
        ReleaseDC(hwnd,winDC);
        break;
    }
    case WM_PAINT: //<<<--------- I replaced the entire segment here with ValidateRect(hwnd,NULL);break; And the whole window doesnt show anymore, why is that so?
    {
        BITMAP infoBM;
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC winDC = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        GetObject(hBitMap, sizeof(infoBM), &infoBM);
        HDC hMem = CreateCompatibleDC(winDC);
        HBITMAP hOldMem = SelectObject(hMem, hBitMap);
        BitBlt(winDC, 0, 0, infoBM.bmWidth, infoBM.bmHeight, hMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
        SelectObject(hMem, hOldMem);
        DeleteObject(hMem);
        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        break;
    }
    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:return DefWindowProcA(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
return 0;
}

INT WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevIstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc = { sizeof(WNDCLASSEX),0,WindowProc,0,0,hInstance,NULL,LoadCursor(NULL,IDC_ARROW),(HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1),NULL,"WindowClass",LoadIcon(NULL,IDI_APPLICATION)};
    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "WINDOW REGISTRATION FAILED", "ERROR", MB_OK);
    }

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_LAYERED, "WindowClass", "Title", WS_POPUP, 200, 200, 300, 300, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    if (!hwnd)
    {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "WINDOW CREATION FAILED", "ERROR", MB_OK);
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    if (!SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, RGB(0, 0, 0), 255, LWA_ALPHA))
    {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "WINDOW LAYERED ATTRIBUTES FAILED", "ERROR", MB_OK);
    }

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, hwnd, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Suggest you add WS_VISIBLE to your CreateWindowEx call.

Comment: Also, start by not making your window proc out to be a liar that claims to return a `BOOL` but in reality does no such thing. And it should return a `LRESULT` regardless. Further, since you process `WM_PAINT` in the posted code, you should be returning `0L` for that, and several other messages (read: almost all messages you directly handle unless specifically called out by the documentation of the message at-hand to do otherwise).

Comment: @WhozCraig apologies for the careless mistakes, I have corrected them in the code above, thanks for pointing them out!

Comment: `BeginPaint` does indeed (among other things) validate the window region previously marked as invalid. The issue is that you're doing your drawing too early. From [`WM_CREATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-create): *"Sent when an application requests that a window be created by calling the `CreateWindowEx` or `CreateWindow` function. **(The message is sent before the function returns.)** The window procedure of the new window receives this message after the window is created, but **before the window becomes visible**."*

Comment: @IInspectable. Thanks! With your explanation, I managed to make everything work with `ValidateRect`  instead of `BeginPaint` by setting a timer at WM_CREATE, then painting the window with `BitBlt` on WM_TIMER, and killing the timer afterwards. :D

Comment: That still won't help in case the window needs to repaint itself for other reasons (e.g. during resize operations). I don't know how repaints are handled when a window gets uncovered after being obscured by another window. The window manager apparently keeps a redirection surface around for desktop composition, but it seems plausible that those surfaces may need to be recreated when the system runs out of resources.

Comment: If you want to use a bitmap as the window display, and don't want to handle `WM_PAINT` to render the bitmap, then you should give the window the `WS_EX_LAYERED` style and give the bitmap to `UpdateLayeredWindow()`. The OS will then handle the rendering of the window for you. If the bitmap ever changes afterwards, simply call `UpdateLayeredWindow()` again with the new bitmap. This way, you don't have to worry about handling (in)validation of the window yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Typically,

> [You use the GetDC function to carry out drawing that must occur
> instantly rather than when a WM_PAINT message is
> processing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/using-the-getdc-function).

And if you'd like, you can [ValidateRect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-validaterect) the entire client area instead of real painting when a WM_PAINT message is processing.
The following code is adapted from [the thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1132628/flickering-in-gdi-drawing-under-win11.html).

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MyWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static int i = 0;
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        if (i++ < 100)
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

            RECT rect;
            GetClientRect(hWnd, &rect);
            COLORREF clrbak = SetBkColor(hdc, RGB(255, 0, 0));
            ExtTextOut(hdc, 0, 0, ETO_OPAQUE, &rect, NULL, 0, NULL);

            int x = (rect.right - rect.left) / 8;
            int y = (rect.bottom - rect.top) / 8;
            rect.left += x; rect.right -= x;
            rect.top += y; rect.bottom -= y;
            SetBkColor(hdc, RGB(0, 255, 0));
            ExtTextOut(hdc, 0, 0, ETO_OPAQUE, &rect, NULL, 0, NULL);



            rect.left += x; rect.right -= x;
            rect.top += y; rect.bottom -= y;
            SetBkColor(hdc, RGB(0, 0, 255));
            ExtTextOut(hdc, 0, 0, ETO_OPAQUE, &rect, NULL, 0, NULL);

            rect.left += x; rect.right -= x;
            rect.top += y; rect.bottom -= y;
            SetBkColor(hdc, RGB(0, 0, 0));
            ExtTextOut(hdc, 0, 0, ETO_OPAQUE, &rect, NULL, 0, NULL);

           SetBkColor(hdc, clrbak);
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        else
        {
            ValidateRect(hWnd,NULL);
        }
    }
    break;
    case WM_ERASEBKGND:
        return 1;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Another point is, as @IInspectable said, Painting the window in WM_CREATE is not reasonable.