# Why do window contents disappear at redraw?

Tags: windows, winapi, rust

A desktop application written in Rust and `winapi` opens a window and adds text lines in several `RedrawWindow()` calls. The text lines come up as expected and persist at (some) resizing, moving and obscuring the window. However, when the window is minimized and opened again, only the last text line is shown; the previous lines are gone. What do I miss in the code?

```
//[dependencies]
//winapi = { version = "0.3.9", features = ["wingdi", "winuser", "libloaderapi", "combaseapi", "objbase", "shobjidl", "winerror"] }

use std::error::Error;
use std::ptr::{null, null_mut};
use std::sync::Mutex;
use std::thread;
use std::time;
use winapi::shared::minwindef::*;
use winapi::shared::windef::*;
use winapi::um::libloaderapi::GetModuleHandleW;
use winapi::um::winuser::*;

// Custom signal to inform that new text is available
pub const WM_WEBUPDT: UINT = 0xFEDC;

/// Turns a Rust string slice into a null-terminated utf-16 vector.
pub fn wide_null(s: &str) -> Vec<u16> {
    s.encode_utf16().chain(Some(0)).collect()
}

static TEXT: Mutex<String> = Mutex::new(String::new());

static mut UPPER_LINE: i32 = 0;

// Window procedure to handle events
pub unsafe extern "system" fn window_proc(
    hwnd: HWND, msg: UINT, wparam: WPARAM, lparam: LPARAM,
) -> LRESULT {
    match msg {
        WM_CLOSE => {
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        }
        WM_DESTROY => {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        }
        WM_WEBUPDT => {
            RedrawWindow(hwnd, null(), null_mut(), RDW_INVALIDATE);
            UPPER_LINE += 25;

        }
        WM_PAINT => {
            let t: String = TEXT.lock().unwrap().clone();
            let mut ps: PAINTSTRUCT = std::mem::zeroed();
            let hdc: HDC;
            hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &mut ps);
            let mut rec: RECT = std::mem::zeroed();
            GetClientRect(hwnd, &mut rec);
            rec.top += 4 + UPPER_LINE;
            let txt = wide_null(&t);
            DrawTextW(
                hdc,
                txt.as_ptr(),
                txt.len().try_into().unwrap(),
                &mut rec,
                DT_TOP | DT_LEFT,
            );
            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        }
        _ => return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam),
    }
    return 0;
}

// Declare class and instantiate window
fn create_main_window(name: &str, title: &str) -> Result<HWND, Box<dyn Error>> {
    let name = wide_null(name);
    let title = wide_null(title);

    unsafe {
        let hinstance = GetModuleHandleW(null_mut());
        let mut wc: WNDCLASSW = core::mem::zeroed();
        wc.lpfnWndProc = Some(window_proc);
        wc.hInstance = hinstance;
        wc.hbrBackground = COLOR_WINDOWFRAME as HBRUSH;
        wc.lpszClassName = name.as_ptr();

        // Register window class
        if RegisterClassW(&wc) == 0 {
            MessageBoxW(
                null_mut(),
                wide_null("Window Registration Failed!").as_ptr(),
                wide_null("Error").as_ptr(),
                MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK,
            );
            return Err("Window Registration Failed".into());
        };
        // Create a window based on registered class
        let handle = CreateWindowExW(
            0,                                // dwExStyle
            name.as_ptr(),                    // lpClassName
            title.as_ptr(),                   // lpWindowName
            WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, // dwStyle
            810,                              // Int x
            390,                              // Int y
            300,                              // Int nWidth
            300,                              // Int nHeight
            null_mut(),                       // hWndParent
            null_mut(),                       // hMenu
            hinstance,                        // hInstance
            null_mut(),                       // lpParam
        );

        if handle.is_null() {
            MessageBoxW( null_mut(),
                wide_null("Window Creation Failed!").as_ptr(),
                wide_null("Error!").as_ptr(), MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK,
            );
            return Err("Window Creation Failed!".into());
        }
        Ok(handle)
    }
}

// Message handling loop
fn run_message_loop(hwnd: HWND) -> WPARAM {
    unsafe {
        let mut msg: MSG = std::mem::zeroed();
        loop {
            // Get message from message queue
            if GetMessageW(&mut msg, hwnd, 0, 0) > 0 {
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessageW(&msg);
            } else {
                // Return on error (<0) or exit (=0) cases
                return msg.wParam;
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    *TEXT.lock().unwrap() = "This is first line".to_string();
    let hwnd = create_main_window("Main Window", "Main Window").expect("Window creation failed!");
    unsafe {
        ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);
        UpdateWindow(hwnd);
    }

    let hwnd2 = hwnd as usize;
    thread::spawn(move || { unsafe {
            thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(100));
            *TEXT.lock().unwrap() = "This is second line".to_string();
            PostMessageW (hwnd2 as HWND, WM_WEBUPDT, 0 as WPARAM, 0 as LPARAM);
            thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(100));
            *TEXT.lock().unwrap() = "This is third line".to_string();
            PostMessageW (hwnd2 as HWND, WM_WEBUPDT, 0 as WPARAM, 0 as LPARAM);
        }
    }
    );
    run_message_loop(hwnd);
}
```

[image: Original]

[image: After]

Comment: You only draw the last line. You're supposed to draw them all. Store and draw all text. Or, draw to a bitmap and blit it to the form (double buffering).

Comment: @GSerg: I draw all lines the same way (at least the second and third). When the window is obscured and redrawn, I do not draw anything at all; Windows does the job, and all lines are present. But after minimization, only the last line is present. I don't understand how this line is different.

Comment: Windows does not do the job. GDI drawing is not persistent. You are only drawing the last line each time, so you are relying on the previous lines to not have been erased, which they will be as you have discovered. Try dragging the window partially off the screen.

Comment: To make it short: you must draw *everything* (corresponding to rcPaint, here it's the whole window) in each WM_PAINT call. Windows buffers nothing.

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, the message ID you assigned to `WM_WEBUPDT` is from a reserved range. `0xC000` through `0xFFFF` is used by [`RegisterWindowMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerwindowmessagew). Since you are implementing a custom window class you should use a message from the range `WM_USER` through `WM_APP - 1`.

Comment: The only thing that Windows does when un-minimizing is to resend a `WM_PAINT` event so that your application can redraw the whole window, but you only redraw the last line, which is why this is the only line that "remains".

Comment: @GSerg: Okey, I overestimated the Windows service since my window *is redrawn from nothing* after it gets obscured. And yes, the data for the last line is still available, so this line will be redrawn after ``WM_PAINT``. Perhaps you can write an answer, so we'll close this case.

Comment: GSerg explained how things used to work. With the introduction of the Desktop Window Manager (in Vista) the system now keeps a DirectX surface including the last rendered window contents around for desktop composition. That explains why you get the behavior you are looking for when uncovering the window. You will find information on how the system (logically) works under [Painting and Drawing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/painting-and-drawing).

Comment: @IInspectable: Thank you. I've scanned this material. It's good to read, but I knew most of it already. It does not explain why an obscured window can be redrawn for free but a minimized one cannot, but I accept this as a fact of life. I understand that it has to do with the Desktop Window Manager and DirectX.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I'm concerned and my test, without handling `WM_ERASEBKGND`,

> [The default handling for the WM_ERASEBKGND message is to fill the area
> with the current window background color](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/window-background).

Also see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74897776/15511041).
At the rest, as comments said, Windows buffers nothing after [Minimized Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/minimized-windows).

> Minimizing a window speeds up system performance by reducing the
> amount of work an application must do when updating its main window.

Comment: Thank you. Could you add some explanation of how the handling of background answers my question? I now know about Windows' limited buffering service. Could you add an explanation of how Windows redraws an obscured window (but not a minimized one)?

Comment: The handling of background doesn't answer your question. My answer means it's impossible that the previous text lines will persist at *resizing* or *obscuring* the window while not handling `WM_ERASEBKGND`. For the second question, you can see [Direct3D Surfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d9/direct3d-surfaces) and [Desktop Window Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dwm/dwm-overview) as @IInspectable explained.

Comment: You haven't tested my program, have you? I *don't handle ``WM_ERASEBKGND``*, but the **text persists when the window is obscured**. The *text also persists when you resize the window* as long as it stays visible; i.e., it will not persist if you make the window so small that the text disappears, but it persists otherwise. I scanned the references very briefly, but I didn't find any explanation of how a window can be redrawn after being obscured. But i really is.

Comment: I have no Rust, but I have tested in a new Windows Desktop Application. My result is what I said. And as far as an obscured window is concerned, `WM_PAINT` is the **only** drawing. You're supposed to draw them all as @GSerg said.

Comment: No, *there must be something special about obscured windows*. You can't use ``WM_PAINT`` when the window reappears because the text in my program would disappear; I can redraw only the last text line, but all text reappears. I use Windows 11 in case it is important. Windows 10 has the same kernel and behaves similarly.

Comment: When windows become obscured, `WM_PAINT` isn't triggered and the client area isn't modified. When obscured windows become normal, `WM_PAINT` is triggered and after that the client area is validated.

Comment: *"When obscured windows become normal, ``WM_PAINT`` is triggered"*: No, this must be **incorrect**. Again, after ``WM_PAINT`` my program only redraws the last line. But when the window becomes normal after being obscured, all text is present.

Comment: Just to inform you. I have recorded obscuring and redrawing the test app on my screen. Unfortunately, you cannot add a video clip on SO. But it definitely works as I've described.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250986/discussion-between-yangxiaopo-msft-and-kalle-svensson).